# log4j level trace and debug didn't show any log

Tags: java, spring, logging, web-applications, log4j

In log4j there are level from trace at the lowest, debug, info, warn, error, and fatal.
I used level info to log my web application with this code

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="abclog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="/data/abc/abc.log"/>
            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.myapp">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="abclog"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.myapp.controller">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="abclog"/>
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

It'd produce abc.log contained log from level info to fatal.

Then I tried to move the error log only to another file, error.log.

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
        <appender name="errorlog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
                <param name="File" value="/data/abc/error.log"/>
                <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
                </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="abclog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
                <param name="File" value="/data/abc/abc.log"/>
                <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
                </layout>
        </appender>

        <logger name="com.myapp">
            <level value="error" />
            <appender-ref ref="errorlog"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.myapp.controller">
            <level value="error" />
            <appender-ref ref="errorlog"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.myapp">
            <level value="info" />
            <appender-ref ref="abclog"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.myapp.controller">
            <level value="info" />
            <appender-ref ref="abclog"/>
        </logger>

    </log4j:configuration>
```

But didn't work, all logger still in abc.log. I found that the logger outputs all those messages equal to that level and also all greater levels than it, that's why the log still in abc.log.

When I deleted abclog and log level info, it worked. It'd show logger from level error (and maybe fatal error if any) on error.log.

But why when I tried to lower the log info to trace / debug without level info or error, it didn't come up with anything, no logger created.

When I put the lowest log4j level, it should show all the log from its level and above like it supposed to do at info level (show log from info to fatal).

- Why could it show up with nothing when the level change into trace / debug instead of level info?
- Does it really no other way to separate error log to another file from other log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the category with additivity set to false. I have not tested, but something like the following should work:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="errorlog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/> 
            <param name="File" value="/data/abc/error.log"/>
            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="abclog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="/data/abc/abc.log"/>
            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- all error from com.myapp to errorlog only --> 
    <category name="com.myapp" additivity="false">
        <priority value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="errorlog"/>
    </category>

    <!-- all other log from com.myapp to abclog only --> 
    <category name="com.myapp" additivity="false">
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="abclog"/>
    </category>

    <root>     
    <!-- all other log to console --> 
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

If you want to separate `com.myapp` and `com.myapp.controller`, you can declare more categories. But you should declare `com.myapp.controller` before `com.myapp`.

UPDATE : you can try with filter perhaps is what you need, after that, I have no more idea:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="errorlog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/> 
            <param name="File" value="/data/abc/error.log"/>
            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
               <param name="levelMin" value="ERROR" />
              <param name="levelMax" value="FATAL" />
            </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="abclog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/> 
            <param name="File" value="/data/abc/abc.log"/>
            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
                <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
               <param name="levelMin" value="INFO" />
              <param name="levelMax" value="WARN" />
            </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%-5p] [%t] {%F:%M:%L} - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- all log from com.myapp to special log file --> 
    <category name="com.myapp" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="errorlog"/>
        <appender-ref ref="abclog"/>
    </category>

    <root>     
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: it worked, all error log is in error.log. But in abclog there's not only info log from package com.myapp and com.myapp.controller only. There's also info log such as abstract handler method mapping and abstract url mapping from java class. 
Is there any way to make separate root log for com.myapp and com.myapp.controller? so it won't show java package log @dams

Comment: if declare category info and error, error log won't show in error log, but abclog. Because level info is lower than error so it will write all log from its level and above. Actually your first code is correct. But I just want to remove default java class package log from abclog and apparently it seem impossible.

Comment: Yes sorry, i make a mistake if you write multiple categories with the same name they will be overwritten and then log is only in abclog